# Alignment Problems in Details and Edit View

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I can't quite figure out how to get this to align properly with mvc 6. There's a CSS tag for "dropdown" but it's just position: relative and doesn't do anything at all.  This was all auto generated scaffolding with Entity Framework.

[image]

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownList("RoleList", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**PAGE SOURCE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Edit - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BDP New User Tool</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Location">Locations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Country">Countries</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Department">Departments</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="wgihBWaaShrDRYvgLvQl0KJsu0kxsOUARHb-vQI02G1yA71ip-y44MmYKFuXBbkLGCvzB1TeOyyC-Zz5NGEWZm9JR-7iRCsmuAv9osMEobzooZglgT4CeWIvvIlKu6wnTLKcAlJo8DW-ci9aD8kV6A2" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="/Manage" title="Manage">Hello nathan.mckaskle@email.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">



<h2>Edit</h2>

<form action="/people/Edit/1" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="P-S-hQ1lZkis-H2u8xV_ovw4chg0_lTzY9gx3h6xJn77k4HqJFQipnnKp5D2TeSFeTciZeACc9iljdDwmKErGepreF-kc3RMf9d1wFPAUlEaqbhAQ8sOBgcXmr0XlRayMEZt1lfA8OfqkpG3_xhN2A2" />    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />

        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PersonId must be a number." data-val-required="The PersonId field is required." id="PersonId" name="PersonId" type="hidden" value="0" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FullName">Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                Nathan McKaskle
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                nathan.mckaskle@email.com
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Roles">Roles</label>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select class="form-control" id="RoleList" name="RoleList"><option selected="selected" value="71758b95-b2b1-410a-8267-ebbd26905102">Admin</option>
<option value="5c0c5cba-fb44-4320-8d9c-e76544e77d60">Basic</option>
<option value="c34e731d-30a2-42e5-9d64-d1c2bd33ef17">Create</option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Roles" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <a href="/people">Back to List</a>
</div>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"fa5c07ac3f3645a88405d2c43af159f5"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:22384/f8c630454ed048b89d34363a3c17c7fe/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: This is an update to my HTML recommended by the answer below. This makes every element on the page scatter all over the place. See next screenshot.

```
@model NewUserTool.Models.PersonViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonId)

        <div class="form-control-static">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-control-static">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-control-static">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownList("RoleList", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-control-static">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Does this:

[image]

Comment: lets see the css that you are trying to modify. what do you want it to look like?

Comment: It's the standard bootstrap.css built in.

Comment: Can you show us the generated html, not your template?

Comment: @SergChernata I have no idea what you're referring to. This is the only html involved in that screen shotted page here. There's the bootstrap.css file that gets generated.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle generated html....in the browser. What your templating generates.

Comment: @SergChernata You mean the source in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DisplayFor` does not accept `htmlAttributes` like `EditorFor` does. The default display for something like `FullName`, a string, is to just dump the string value without any HTML, so in most cases, there's nothing to actually add attributes to. However, even if this did work, you'd still be using the wrong class here, as what you're looking for is actually `form-control-static` which styles text to align as if it was an input with class `form-control`. So the code you actually need is:

```
<p class="form-control-static">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Email)</p>
```

Also, your drop down is misaligned because you're not passing the HTML attributes correctly. The anonymous object within an anonymous object syntax is for `EditorFor`. That parameter in `EditorFor` is actually for additional view data. In effect, you're adding a key to `ViewData` called `htmlAttributes` and the default editor templates look for this key in `ViewData` and do something with it. However, in the case of helpers like `TextBoxFor`, `DropDownListFor`, etc. the parameter, itself, is for HTML attributes. As a result, you're telling it to add an attribute called `htmlAttributes` and give it the value of that anonymous object, which I'm not even sure what the helper would do with. Long and short, change the code to:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleList", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Wow now everything is all over the page in different places.

Comment: That change alone would not cause that. There's something else wrong. Post your updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Within your `html`, you never properly wrapped the `dropdown`. If you have a row, make sure to declare columns, totaling 12.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Roles">Roles</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <select class="form-control" id="RoleList" name="RoleList"><option selected="selected" value="71758b95-b2b1-410a-8267-ebbd26905102">Admin</option>
                <option value="5c0c5cba-fb44-4320-8d9c-e76544e77d60">Basic</option>
                <option value="c34e731d-30a2-42e5-9d64-d1c2bd33ef17">Create</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Roles" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I did wrap your text into `p` tags and apply the same top margin as the labels.

https://jsfiddle.net/a3abkffj/

Comment: How does that look in the actual cshtml file?

Comment: Just wrap your dropdown into `<div class="col-md-10">`

Comment: @SergChemata That worked for the drop down but not for the other text.